# Rails - Validation across two forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have what seems to be a non-standard signup process:

[welcome! enter your email and password] => [cool, enter a lot more information] => [registered]

I'm having trouble getting rails to recognize that I want to validate only the email and password on page 1, and all the other stuff on page 2.

When the user hits the site, they see my welcome page:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.new        
  end 
end


<%= form_for(@user) do %>           
            <div class="formItem">
                <%= label_tag(:email, "Your email address:") %>
                <%= text_field(:user, :email) %>
                <br clear="all" />
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <%= label_tag(:password, "Select a password:") %>
                <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
                <br clear="all" />
            </div>              
            <%= submit_tag("Sign up today - it's free and easy!", :class => "submitForm") %>                
        <% end %>
```

=

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user]) 
    if @user.save   
      redirect_to(edit_user_path(@user, :noticeHeader => true ), :notice => 'Please take a minute and answer these additional questions.')                       
      else
        render :action => "welcome/index"
    end
  end
```

=

Once they click Sign Up, they see my next page of form fields.

The problem I'm running into is that I validates_presence_of fields that are on both pages, in the user model. Since these fields aren't on the welcome page, I get a "**undefined local variable or method**" error upon submitting the welcome page. For example, I **validates_presence_of :title** because I want title to be required, but it's only listed on page 2, so page 1 doesn't validate properly.

Thoughts on how to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into one of these plugins/gems where you can create Wizard based forms.
http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_wizards.html my favourite is "ActsAsWizard"